# GIDSignInDelegate methods not calling in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode7, google-signin

I have implemented `google signIn`in my App.

It is working fine in `iOS 9+`. But it is creating issue in `8+` version.

I have initialized google sign in as:

```
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
```

In my `button` click following code is their:

```
    - (void)userDidTapSignInButton:(UIButton*)sender {

        [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];

    }
```

Only this `Google Delegate` is being called:

```
    - (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {

        NSLog(@"Show Sign In Screen");

   }
```

After this `Google Sign` in page opens. After entering my user login Details when I press confirm and Done then I am redirected back to my app. After this nothing happens.

Neither Success not Failed delegate is called.

```
  - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
          didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
 withError:(NSError *)error {
       NSLog(@"Google Sign IN SUccess");
   }
```

Failure Delegate:

```
  - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
     didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
 withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"google sign in fail with error");
   }
```

When I run my app in iOS 9.2 or 9.3 it works well every delegate is being called. But Not in iOS 8.4,8.3,...

I am not able to figure out the cause behind it.

Also I am not getting any logs or error message in console.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the ios 9.0 version and the ios 8.0 version of the open url function.

```
   @available(iOS 8.0,*)
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    print("sign in with annotation")
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                annotation: annotation)
}
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print("sign in with options")
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
                                                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. When posting an answer, try to be more informative: explain the error you have found and the solution you have posted: see also how to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hello RahulMishra, have you done google sign in integration through cocoa pods or iOS sdk?